# Need help with some Vector math

Tags: vectors

*ox*, *oy* are coordinates of object (box) center and they are know. *Forward* is a normal vector also know. *Up* is a another normal vector, also known and perpendicular to *forward* vector. Box *W* (width) and *H* (height) is known. *x*, *y* (*A*) is also a know point coordinate. What I need to calculate is distance between *A* and *B* - it should be positive or negative depending on each side the point *A* is. Please help!

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the orthogonal component of $(x,y)-(o_x,o_y)$ w.r.t. the direction of the vector $\text{Up}$, which is $$\frac{\langle(x,y)-(o_x,o_y);\text{Up}\rangle}{\sqrt{\langle\text{Up};\text{Up}\rangle}}=\frac{(x-o_x)\text{Up}_x+(y-o_y)\text{Up}_y}{\sqrt{\text{Up}_x^2+\text{Up}_y^2}}$$

Comment: This works, but doesn't change sign when being up or down :(

Comment: Yes it does.${}$

Comment: Yeah. It does. Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

Let $v$ be the vector from $A$ to $(ox,oy)$.  Let $w$ be the projection of $v$ onto the forward vector.  All these these quantities are known.   Then a vector from $A$ to $B$ is given by $v-w$.  The length of this is the distance you want.

Comment: I dont understand the projection part :/

Comment: It's what dot product (or inner product) is all about.  You can't really do vector stuff without it.  The formula in Gae S.'s answer is based on it.